# How can you implement ZipLongest in Rx?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I'm trying to Zip two observable sequences of different lengths but I want the combined sequence to have the length of the largest sequence, padded with the last value of the shortest sequence.

That is, if sequence 1 is [0,1,2] and sequence 2 is [0,1,2,3], I would like the result to be [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)].

I've tried to think of ways of implementing this in terms of existing operators such as Zip or CombineLatest but it actually seems to be a bit trickier than would appear at first glance.

Comment: I don't suppose you know the lengths of the observable sequences ahead of time?

Comment: No, I don't, but I'm still curious how that would help...

Comment: I was thinking of concatenating a repeating sequence of the last value produced of the shorter sequence, but knowing which is shorter and how long the longer is is needed for that. It was a bad idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt at it, based upon Enigmativity's idea:

```
aSource.Publish(ap => bSource.Publish(bp =>
    {
        var lastA = ap.TakeLast(1).Replay();
        var lastB = bp.TakeLast(1).Replay();
        var lastAForEachB = bp.SelectMany(b => lastA);
        var lastBForEachA = ap.SelectMany(a => lastB);

        var aWithLengthB = ap.Concat(lastAForEachB);
        var bWithLengthA = bp.Concat(lastBForEachA);

        lastA.Connect();
        lastB.Connect();
        return aWithLengthB.Zip(bWithLengthA, (a, b) => new { a, b });
    }));
```